# Find value in an Object using only the Key JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an object containing a checklist below that I would like to get values from.

```
colors = {
    green: true, 
    blue: true, 
    red: true, 
    orange: false
}
```

How will I get the value (e.g. true/false) just by using the keys?

Pseudocode:

```
const isUsed = (color) => {
    return if true or false given the color
}
```

Expectations:

```
console.log(isUsed("green"));
//logs true
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(colors["green"]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const colors = {
    green: true, 
    blue: true, 
    red: true, 
    orange: false
}


const isUsed = (color) => {
    return colors[color]
}

console.log(isUsed('green'))
console.log(isUsed('orange'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const isUsed = color => colors[color]
```

This will return true or false if the value color exists in colors, or it will return undefined if it doesn't